# IBM Cloud - Cloud Foundry - Disable SSL Renegotiation in mybluemix.net domain

Tags: ssl, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

In IBM Cloud Foundry, how can I disable SSL Renegotiation or check for client-initiated renegotiation support and disable it where possible?